# What is the limit of the indeterminate form of 1/0?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have been asked to use L'Hopital's rule to calculate the following:

$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} \cdot \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{x}} - 1}
$$

This limit is not in the indeterminate form of $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ like I have been taught, so I cannot use L'Hopital's rule yet.

I believe that the equation must be algebraically transformed somehow to get the intermediate form, but I don't know how to. Can someone please help me out?

Also, I am used to looking at graphs and finding limits from above and below a certain value, but is there a way to do it without having to graph the equation each time (so I can save time in exams)?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that the title is misleading: this is not "1/0".

Comment: $1/0$ is not indeterminate is a black hole!!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$\displaystyle\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{e^{1/x}-1}$$

Now, it is in $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ form.

Comment: Is it not 1/0 on the top still?

Comment: You are looking it with the wrong eye. 1/0 is not indeterminate.

Comment: I gave it some thought, and I finally understand. Thank you very much. (I used only the right eye to see the equation, and I finally understood)

Answer (score 4):

Putting $x = \frac1t$ you get
$$
\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x(e^{1/x}-1)} = \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{t}{e^t-1}
$$
which you may find easier to handle.